# ImportError: cannot import name 'calinski_harabaz_score' from 'sklearn.metrics'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I was trying to import :

```
from aikit.ml_machine import MlMachineLauncher
```

But I got the error :

```
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_score, calinski_harabaz_score, davies_bouldin_score
ImportError: cannot import name 'calinski_harabaz_score' from 'sklearn.metrics'
```

I tried try/except but without result :

```
try:
    from sklearn.metrics import calinski_harabasz_score
except ImportError:
    from sklearn.metrics import calinski_harabaz_score
```

I have scikit-learn v0.23.2

Comment: I have `python 3.7.6` and `scikit-learn==0.22.1` works fine for me.

Comment: The same here, but I have always the same error

Comment: even I dont get an error

Comment: did you have an error after using try except

Comment: Did you use "pip install aikit" ? And if so, what does "pip show aikit" return?

Comment: I get the same error. Then, I have created a virtual env and installed everything from 0 then it worked. Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Because they have changed the name to

```
calinski_harabasz_score
```

from

```
calinski_harabaz_score
```

just add the following line and your problem is solved

```
from sklearn.metrics import calinski_harabasz_score
```

Answer (score 0):

We just released a new version `0.2.2` which fixes the compatibility with `sklearn>=0.23`.

You can now update both:

````
pip install scikit-learn==0.23.2
pip install aikit==0.2.2
```
````